# Fetch API failed to recognize response.status

Tags: redux, promise, fetch-api

I'm just trying to fetch data using Fetch API . Here's my code

```
    function status(response) {  
    return response.json().then( data => {
        if(response === 200) {  
            return data
        }else if(response.status === 400){
            let message = data.error.error.error[0]
            return Promise.reject({status: response.status, message});
        }else if(response.status === 401){
            let message = data.message
            return Promise.reject({status: response.status, message});
        }else{  
            return Promise.reject({status: response.status, data});    
        }  
    })
    }

export function getAgenda(limit, offset, status){
    return (dispatch)=>{
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_AGENDA_REQUEST'
        })

        const token = loadCred().token

        api.fetchAgenda(limit, offset, status, token)
            .then(status) 
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(data) // this is printed in console
                dispatch({
                  type: 'FETCH_AGENDA_SUCCESS',
                  payload: { 
                    ...data,
                    totalPages: Math.ceil(data.totalRows / limit) 
                    }
                })  
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error) // not this one
                dispatch({
                  type: 'FETCH_AGENDA_ERROR',
                  payload: {
                    error
                  }
                });
            })
    }
}
```

Since Fetch API consider 400++ as a resolved Promise, I tried to filter them first using Status function. But it turned out that error 401 considered a Resolved rather than Rejected. I tried to check but error in console wasn't printed by catch.

[image: error in console not printed by catch]

Comment: If the server doesn’t send back the Access-Control-Allowed-Origin response header in the response, then your browser will block from your frontend JavaScript code from reading any properties of the response — including the `.status` property — even though you can still use devtools to view the properties of the response. And most servers won’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to 4xx (error) responses — instead they generally only add them to 2xx (success) responses.

Comment: then what should I do to handle this properly ?@sideshowbarker

Comment: I found this article https://css-tricks.com/using-fetch/ and it works well. It seems similar but somehow my code didn't work. I'll try to analize later. thanks @sideshowbarker

Answer (score 0):

Your status function could return a resolved promise or otherwise a rejected promise (throwing an error makes the catch statement blocks it).

```js
function main() {
    // call fetchAgenda api
    api.fetchAgenda(
    // what you are doing here
        // ...
    // return a response object
    ).then(
        response => status(response)
    // resolved promise returned by status call
    ).then(
        data => console.log(data);
    // rejected promise returned by status call
    ).catch(
        error => console.log(error);
    );
}

function status(response) {
    // if response is ok (200 - 299) or is less than 400
    if (response.ok || response.status < 400) {
        // it's good, convert it into json
        return response.json();
    }
    else {
        // response isn't fine, reject promise...
        return Promise.reject(response);
        // ... or throw an error
        // return throw Error(response);
    }
}
```